# Form onSubmit function not firing when form submitted

Tags: javascript, html

I have had a look and cannot find anything like my problem.

I have a form where I cannot get the validation to work. I know the JavaScript file is loading since other functions on the page are working without issue. My code is as follows:

```
  <form method="post" name="selectMod" action="check.php" onsubmit="validate()">
```

There is then the form and the button is coded as follows:

```
  <div class="form-row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block center-block">Submit</button>
```

At the moment the code in the function is set to just return false since I cannot get it to work.

```
  function validate(){
  return false;
  }
```

Sure I am missing something obvious but cannot see what it is.

Comment: Please, share a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: use <input type='submit' value='Submit'/> instead of <button>

Comment: What do you mean you cannot get it to work? Are there any errors?

Comment: I have amended the button code to the above and still no joy. @BoyWithSilverWings I would expect the form to not submit but it does.

Comment: You are returning `false` from `validate()` function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is firing. It just doesn't *do* anything with observable effects.

1. The `onsubmit` function calls `validate`
2. The `validate` function returns `false` (because it has a `return` statement)
3. The `onsubmit` function ignores that return value
4. The `onsubmit` function returns `undefined` (because it doesn't have a `return` statement

If you want to prevent the default behaviour of the submit event, then you need to `return false` from the `onsubmit` function

```
onsubmit="return validate()"
```

---

Modern code would avoid intrinsic event attributes in favour of binding event listers with JavaScript and manipulating the event object.

```
var myForm = document.querySelector("form");
myForm.addEventListener("submit", validate);
function validate(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks this helps a lot. Turns out my main issues were being caused by XAMPP not supporting validation. Once I did it locally it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following:

```
 function validate(){
    //if check false
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
 }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

on check() function, there is invalid syntax **getEforlementById**

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).